# Best way to compare one column value with the words contained in the other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

My table structure is something like below.

```
Products { product_name, brand, model}
```

All are varchar fields (there are more fields but they are not related to my issue. There are nearly 5000000 in this table.

Now what I need do is, I want go through all products and check if product_name contains any other products brand and Model ( not part of words but full words, so product name should contain model as one word and brand as one word), if so store somewhere that these are same products.

I have looked into full text indexes with co-related sub query approach but then come to know that CONTAINS function is not accepting column name as second word and I also don't if somehow this is achieved how fast it will be.

Any recommendation for doing the same will be very helpful for me.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Would this not be possible with `like` and `exists`?

```
select * from Products p
where exists(select * from Products 
             where p.product_name != product_name 
             and (' ' + p.product_name + ' ' like '% ' + brand + ' % ' + model + ' %'
                or ' ' + p.product_name + ' ' like '% ' + model + ' % ' + brand + ' %'))
```

Comment: Thanks @muhmud for coming with something, functionally yes this will kinda work for me but this is extremely slow considering the number of records I have to process, this takes forever.

Comment: Is this a one off thing, or do you need to do it regularly?